# How to create a multi value textbox?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to create a multi value text box in asp.net for tagging like stack overflow ?

So please let me know how Can I do that ?

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Answer (score 0):

Set `TextMode` to "MultiLine"

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="Comment"
       TextMode="MultiLine"
       Columns="50"
       Rows="5"
       runat="server"/>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx

You can google for 'Javascript Tag Control' in order to find javascript implementations that may be closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand correctly you need an autocomplete control. The most easiest way is to utilize the AutoCompleteExtender from the AjaxControlToolkit: [AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)
Also if you are experienced in jQuery and Ajax you may use a jQuery autocomplete plugin like this one: [Plugins/Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)